# Hover on the text to change size using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the size of the text when Hover over the word Internet, without changing any of its other properties. When over over the word I am trying to `decrease` the size of the word

Here is my code that I tried to achieve this functionality

```
h1:hover::before,
h1:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1::after {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;

}
#text:hover{
color:white;
```

-webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
    }

```
<body>
  <div class="text-wrapper">


    <h1 id='text'>
      Hot</h1>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: by changing font-size ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but no update on my code

Comment: where? we don't see any font-size update

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: `   #text:hover{
    color:white;
font-size:12px; 
    }` right?

Comment: yes and as you can see it's working fine but with a strange animation as you are decreasing it a lot and without transition

Comment: you can also try to use scale() instead of font-size

Comment: What changes should I make here? I am not sure how transition works

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments suggested, you need to add a transition to the `h1` css:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #6849e3;
    font-family: Merriweather;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    // Set transition...
    transition: transform .7s ease;
}
```

And set a low scale transform:

```
#text:hover {
    color: white;
    // Scale transform...
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Fiddle around with the scale setting and the transition duration to adjust size of the text and the speed of transition respectively.

**Edit:**

If I have understood your comment correctly, you want the on hover lines to animate its width and then "disappear" - we can just reverse the animation from full width to nothing for that. For this you need to use the `animation` attribute along with `@keyframes`.

I have changed the lines the other way round so the top line goes from right to left and bottom line from left to right as per your comment, by changing the `h1::before` left attribute to `right:0;` and vice-versa for the `h1::after`.

Then you need to specify the animation on the hover rule:

```
h1:hover::before,
h1:hover::after {
   animation-name: slide;
   animation-duration: .5s;
   animation-iteration-count: 2;
   animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

For more information on the `animation` attributes: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

And specify the animation itself via `@keyframes`:

```
@keyframes slide {
  from {width:0%}
  to {width:100%}
}
```

Info on the `@keyframes`: [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```css
body {
  Background: #7a86cb;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #6849e3;
  font-family: Merriweather;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .7s ease;
}


h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #6849e3;
}

h1:hover::before,
h1:hover::after {
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-duration: .5s;
 animation-iteration-count: 2;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}

h1::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h1::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
 
}
#text:hover{
  color:white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
@keyframes slide {
  from {width:0%}
  to {width:100%}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text-wrapper">


    <h1 id='text'>
      INTERNET </h1>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, I figured out thank you. Could you help me with the line at the top and the bottom. When hover the word I am for the top line to go from R-> L and the disappear, viceversa for bottom line

Comment: @osama I've edited my answer. You need to use the `animation` attribute and `@keyframes` to do this: see answer and snippet.